# Error installing ADT 22.3 offline

Tags: android, eclipse

I tried to install adt 23.3.0 in eclipse 3.7 offline, 
I download ADT-22.3.0.zip(I found that the ZIP file is not damaged)  and i went to HELP->INSTALL NEW SOFTWARS clicked add and then chosed the zip file and i get this error message:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
Software being installed: Android Development Tools 22.3.0.v201310242005-887826
(com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 22.3.0.v201310242005-887826)
Missing requirement: Android Development Tools 22.3.0.v201310242005-887826
(com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 22.3.0.v201310242005-887826) requires 
'org.eclipse.wst.sse.core 0.0.0' but it could not be found
```

I have no idea how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice is to use the Android Studio, I've noticed much difference with Eclipse and worth, here I share a link for you, to download it easier.

Windows:
http://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/ide-zips/0.4.6/android-studio-ide-133.1028713-windows.zip

Mac:
http://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/ide-zips/0.4.6/android-studio-ide-133.1028713-mac.zip